# Is it possible to automate the submission of an application to the Windows Store?

Tags: windows-store-apps, uwp, windows-store

I want to more rapidly release updates for my application. Is it possible to call Web APIs from the Windows store to publish updates to my Windows 10 apps directly to the Store without manual interaction?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know .. there's no official API from Microsoft for that, you could ask for that : https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform .